# Custom DisplayForm using JSLink

Tags: jslink, display-form, csom

Is there any way to customise the display form of a list using the Client Site Templates e.g.

```
// Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
```

I know you can override each fields render handler doing something like this

```
 overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Title': {
            'DisplayForm': customDisplayField //override display form
        }
    }   

    // Register the template overrides.
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
```

But this doesn't allow me to change the layout of the form or remove the labels associated with each field

Comment: You can also create your own Custom Display Form. Some ideas here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166156/make-task-form-field-read-only-using-sharepoint-designer/166170#166170 and here: https://afrait.com/blog/tag/form/

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can use JSLink to customize forms, but I never choose that approach. It depends on your skillset and the resources available to you. Usually, when we want to customize a form we do a custom JavaScript form from scratch. It just ends up being easier that way because even starting with simple changes we usually end up doing more later and more complicated customizations once users get their hands on things. So custom ends up being better in the long run.

One same using JSLink is listed above. Here is another: 
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSR-code-samples-11-Fully-54ebcaa6

I've also been meaning to check out Stratus Forms. I haven't yet, but they're from Mark Rackley and he really knows his stuff. I recommend checking them out as a forms customization approach. http://www.stratusforms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still a problem for you, but I've solved this problem by using the OnPostRender functionality of JSLink.

The link below shows how to use the event to hide forms.  (I wouldn't use this if data security is a big deal, only if the layout needs to be changed, or labels changed, etc.)

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-a52cf8a7