# Make Task Form Field Read-Only using SharePoint Designer

Tags: form, task-list

How would I make a task-form field (`SP2013`) **read-only** (*not hidden*) using **SharePoint Designer**?

Comment: did you find anything new here?

Comment: I've been working on it the last couple days.  Actually, the first link you provided seemed to be the most helpful.  I have successfully changed the fields I need to read only, now am only struggling with hiding the 'content type' at the top of the task form.  Something about finding and hiding specific text in an h3 header?

Comment: Well, to hide something the best approach might be css. But I can not help you there. Still a SharePoint beginner. Maybe here some inspiration http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140634/how-to-hide-remove-fields-from-the-default-editform-for-my-enterprisewiki-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to give you a guideline here (Pictures are in German, but the essential part is good to understand I guess):

I will show you how to set the priority field as read only. Here the default view:

[image]

1. Open your list in SharePoint Designer

[image]

2. Create a new form

[image]

3. I created a new form for new entries / items / tasks (be sure to give it a new name "CustomNewForm", set it as a "newForm" and set it as default)

[image]

4. Open the newly created form in advanced mode. (just right click onto the form and then ... advanced mode)

[image]

5. Now look for you field (in this case "Priority") and here the important part is the ControlMode. This is set to "new" (because of the newForm).

[image]

6. Change those two values from "New" to "Display" and **save** the form.

[image]

7. After that, if you create a new entry / item / task in your list, the priority field should be read only.

[image]

Hope this helps. If so, please give it a **vote up** or mark it as answer if it fits perfectly for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Patrick.  I'm not quite seeing the same lines of code though (or any referencing form field at all).  The only line containing the control mode is the following, ControlMode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2

Comment: Could this be because I am editing the 'Edit' form?

Comment: Please check in the answer above Step 2 & 3. You have to create a new form. Otherwise you wont have the field as in the answer.

Comment: I see.  But is there a way to use the existing editform?  I have created content types to manage the forms and am applying via workflow.  Maybe jslink on the web part somehow?

Comment: didn't test it, but maybe you can try this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Sample-8-List-add-and-edit-d228b751 or give this a chance: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/06/24/customize-fields-in-newform-aspx-hidedisablepre-populate-with-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/