# SharePoint EditForm add new button to footer

Tags: edit-form, save

How can I add button to footer of EditForm next to `Save` and `Cancel` buttons?

I want my new button to Save Changes and then Redirect to NewForm. I haven't come across anything that useful, maybe someone who has done it, can help?

I'm meaning something like this:

[image]

Comment: Not the answer, but the way you have to go: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172280/how-to-design-the-sharepoint-list-newform-aspx/172283#172283 and here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/166156/make-task-form-field-read-only-using-sharepoint-designer/166170#166170

Comment: I had a similar requirement. I ended up with removing the Save button from the bottom of the form completely and adding an additional save button in the ribbon. If that would be a solution to your problem, I can post the code.

Comment: Going to check those links out, I prefer to keep those buttons down below.

Answer (score 2):

#### Add the URL of the next (current) form as the &Source=[url] parameter

The Source parameter in the URL is where the browser is redirected to after a Form is saved. Default behaviour is to return to the AllItems View.

Open an EditForm and investigate the URL

(the same construct can be used on a NewForm)

The URL has to be URL encoded (and it needs to be within the SharePoint domain)

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/iCSR/Lists/Tasks/NewForm.aspx
?Source=
 https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FiCSR%2FLists%2FTasks%2FAllItems%2Easpx
&RootFolder=
```

So if you replace that Source with URL of your NewForm

```
https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2FiCSR%2FLists%2FTasks%2FNewForm.aspx
```

You can add an item and then be returned to a Blank NewForm

You might also be interested in:

#### [Limit only one entry per day per user in sharepoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153059/limit-only-one-entry-per-day-per-user-in-sharepoint-list)

Answer (score 1):

I did it quickly. Follow the links I posted and create a new EditForm.aspx.

The essential part ist this:

```
        <tr>
        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="ms-descriptiontext" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Edit" runat="server"/>
                    </td>                       
                    <td>
                    <input type="button" class="contact-button" value="Save + Redirect" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={NewForm.aspx}')}" />
                    </td>
                    <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                    <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                        <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server"  ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="ms-separator"> </td>
                    <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                        <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here the CustomEditForm.aspx

[image]

You can also place the button in between the columns. Just take the three lines:

```
<td>
  <input type="button" class="contact-button" value="Save + Redirect" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={CustomNewForm.aspx}')}" />
</td>
```

and place it somewhere in between. e.G. I placed it between the lines 125-129.

[image]

After that the CustomEditForm looks like that:

[image]

Comment: Nice, going to test it out, hopefully it works! :)

Comment: Any news here? Did it help?

Comment: Yes, this method does indeed work, there are just other problems, since I need to custom layout and custom amount of fields. For that there is a script, that hides all fields and displays, what are needed. Currently with that it doesn't seem to have good easy integration. If `ContentLink` tells you anything.

Comment: But is there a way, that I could just add this button to random place in content and it would do the same job? Currently, when I add this input directly to content, it doesn't do anything

Comment: updated the answer. Hope this helps

Comment: Well the problem begins with this custom form, somehow/why it breaks, when there are fields displayed on it. When I try to add this button to my in WebPart (reading in JS content file), then this button doesn't work there.